# Why Spacy always recognising apple as an Organisation

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

In named entity recognition Spacy always recognizing apple as an organization, never recognizing as a fruit.

I tried the below code:

```
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc= nlp(u'Apple is my favourite fruit , it\'s cost around \u20B9 10 in India')
for token in doc:
    print(token,end='|')
print('\n....')

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text+'-'+ent.label_+'-'+str(spacy.explain(ent.label_)))
```

The output was : 
[image: ![output image][1]][1]
Why Spacy is not recognizing apple as fruit and ₹10 as monetary value.

Please help me on this.

Regards,

Venkat

Comment: Have you tried with another model like `_sm` or `_md` and see if it has difference? I noticed some difference on various words using different models... And I am not sure there is something you can do, maybe try to re-define your own Entity but it's a bit of hack imo :)

Comment: Hi FIo, Thank you for response. I tried _sm but it is also recognizing apple as organization

Comment: I believe Apple (with capital A) is recognized as a named entity. When altering it to lowercase, it becomes a noun. Also when I run your code, `10` is detected as a "CARDINAL" label_ (number that does not fall under another type). When I use 'en_core_web_sm' it now finds `around ₹ 10` as a entity. I found this link to the spaCy issues: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1332 but it doesn't give a solution for your specific issue.

Comment: Try using Flair instead of Spacy. Spacy's NER performance isn't that high.